# Unable to duplicate android project

Tags: android, duplicates

I have an android project (named project1) which I thought I have duplicated by doing the following, as per what I learnt online.

1) Shut off Android Studio and using Windows Explorer, copied the project1 folder elsewhere.

2) Renamed the copied folder from project1 to project2

3) Launch Android Studio and import a new project pointing to the folder location of project2

4) Refactor and rename the package from com.something.project1 to com.something.project2

5) Changed the appname in the string.xml to project2 instead of project1.

After all is done above, I build APKs for project1 and project2 thinking I've made two different apps.

But when I tried it install 'project1' and run on my phone, the app I install works fine, but when attempting to install the 'second app', i.e. project2, it tells me its the same app as 'project1' and what I am essentially doing is updating project1 instead of installing a new app, project2?

What did I do wrong, or what did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Update your Android manifest, make sure you update the class path references and name too. Thats what clashes. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

open your second project of `com.something.project1`
and now press `Ctrl+Shift+F`  and now in this opened window enter your old `com.something.project1` here..and find..so it will search through whole project..if you found anywhere then replace with `com.something.project2`...

Even after than look on manifest & build.gradle file... there we need replace also..
run & build..